# Are there any conflicts with casting Fire Wings while Wild Shaped?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, wild-shape

I have the natural spell feat already. I was curious if there were any rules about layering transmutation spells and the wording of said spells interacting with a druid's wild shape ability.

Spell in question, with the bit that caught my attention:

> Fire Wings (Spell Compendium, p. 93) (Transmutation [Fire]): In a flash of light and a roar of fire, your arms become wings of flame ... If you are not flying, you can make up to two attacks each round with the fire wings as if they were natural weapons. A successful attack deals 2d6 points of fire damage.

Because replacing the 2 claws of a wild shape with 2d6 fire damage phoenix wings would be a cool spell interaction. I'm just not sure if there's a solid rule on layering transmutation spells or if the spell's specific wording of "arms" would throw the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [rules on combining magic effects](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#combiningMagicalEffects) do not get into such specific details, but generally speaking the goal of those rules is for things to work (as much as possible):

> Spells or magical effects usually work as described, no matter how many other spells or magical effects happen to be operating in the same area or on the same recipient. Except in special cases, a spell does not affect the way another spell operates.

And there are rules for creatures without arms to use “arm slot” magic items, which is precedent for replacing forelegs with wings from *fire wings*.

> Creatures with more than two legs can treat their foremost pair of limbs as their arms (allowing them access to the arms, hands, and rings body slots), even if those limbs are used for locomotion rather than for manipulation.

<sup>(*Magic Item Compendium* pg. 219)</sup>

But ultimately the specifics of any spell interaction is going to be up to the DM to adjudicate. I kind of doubt any DMs are likely to have much objection here, but you’ll have to ask yours to be sure.